# VBA code not stable

Tags: vba, excel

It started on Monday this week, when I finished with my code,the codes purpose was to pull data from a specific sheet in a specific folder from all spreadsheets in that folder.

But just last night he started crashing  excel spreadsheet every time i pushed the run button.

Any idea why?

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportSheet()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim FileList As Variant
    Dim GrabSheet As String
    Dim FileType As String
    Dim ActWorkBk As String
    Dim ImpWorkBk As String
    Dim NoImport As Boolean
Application.EnableEvents = False
    SourceFolder = "C:\Users\Jarryd.Ward\Desktop\Test\"
    FileType = "*.xlsx"
    GrabSheet = "Summary"
    FileList = ListFiles(SourceFolder & "/" & FileType)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActWorkBk = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    NoImport = False

    For i = 1 To UBound(FileList)
        Workbooks.Open (SourceFolder & "\" & FileList(i))
        ImpWorkBk = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        On Error Resume Next
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(GrabSheet).Select
            If Err > 0 Then
                NoImport = True
                GoTo nxt
            End If
            Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(GrabSheet).Copy After:=Workbooks(ActWorkBk).Sheets(Workbooks(ActWorkBk).Sheets.Count)
           ActiveSheet.Name = ImpWorkBk

        On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.Name = FileList(i) & " - " & GrabSheet
            Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo 0
nxt:
        Workbooks(ImpWorkBk).Activate
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Workbooks(ActWorkBk).Activate
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Relying on activeworkbook/worksheet is not ideal, have you tried creating workbook/worksheet objects and setting them explicitly? Also what error occurs? complete excel crash? a VB error when running the macro?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code using F8 to at least see what is working? Also, "crashes Excel" is a little vague. Can you be more specific in what is happening?

Comment: If you have edited your code extensively before release you may want to look into using something like RibbonCommander to clean you project. Since VBA doesn't clean up after itself, you may encounter instances where the code becomes corrupt. Frankly, I dont know why or how this happens, but I have had this issue with multiple large VBA projects and the issue has been remedied since I started cleaning them with RC. Here's a link: http://www.ribboncommander.com/download. This isn't an excuse to not get rid of "ActiveWorkbook" and "Activesheet" references though.

Comment: Hi guys, first off, thank you for the replies. I am going to elaborate. I have to create a macro that directs to a folder with a lot of spreadsheets saved on a daily basis, I want to copy the first sheet in each spreadsheet and paste them into a master workbook, I want the sheets to roll in the master workbook, i.e. I want the first sheet copy to paste on the first sheet in master, second one to paste in second sheet and so on (that is what I mean by roll). The problem I have is that whenever I run the program my excel crashes and stops working

Comment: I am unable to download the ribbon commander because of the company I work in and website restrictions they have, can ask someone to try download it for me with the correct authority.

Comment: I will step through it now and let you know

Comment: The workbooks.open(SourceFolder & "\" & FileList(i)) is the point where it starts to crash

Comment: and by excel crash, it just says excel has stopped working

Answer (score 1):

Try opening and closing your files this way to see if it helps.  It should minimize the calls to activate this or that.  And closing out by variable instead of activesheet will insure that your code isn't trying to close the main workbook by accident.

```
Sub testOpen()
Dim manyWBs As Workbook
Dim myWB As Workbook


Set myWB = ThisWorkbook


For Each file In folder
    Set manyWBs = Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\filename")


'   do events.......
manyWBs.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B13").Copy _
       Destination:=myWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:b13")




    manyWBs.Close
    Set manyWBs = Nothing
Next file




Set myWB = Nothing
End Sub
```